# a sentence+comma+ noun+ relative clause?

Tags: sentence-structure

A sentence from an ACT English test:

> The cable is designed to stretch to twice its normal length, a feature that allows it to adapt to harsh sea conditions and also keeps the buoy above water at all times.

I do not grasp the structure "a sentence+comma+ noun+ that clause." Why does a noun with a relative clause set alone? Is it sort of like an absolute structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part starting with "a feature", "a feature that allows it to adapt to harsh sea conditions and also keeps the buoy above water at all timmes", is a noun phrase which is made up of a head and a dependent component. The head of the noun phrase (NP) is "feature", followed by a relative clause "that allows it to..."

Preceding the NP is the main clause of the sentence. The noun phrase is attached to it as an [appositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition), serving to explain the main clause. Appositives can usually be expanded with a relative pronoun and a verb to become a relative clause. Therefore, without changing the meaning you can also say:

> The cable is designed to stretch to twice its normal length, [which is] a feature that allows it to adapt to harsh sea conditions and also keeps the buoy above water at all times.